# Unable to make JDBC connection with SpringORM and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-orm

I'm trying a simple SpringORM program which will fetch data from MySQL and display the data in it. But when trying to run the application, it shows unable to make the JDBC connection. Beans for the JDBC connection is below

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydatabase"></property>
<property name="user" value="root"></property>
<property name="password" value=""></property>

<property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
</bean>
```

And my Dao class for connecting with database is as follows
package com.thiluxan.springorm.dao;

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.thiluxan.springorm.model.*;
//import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.SessionFactory;

@Component
public class StudentDao {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    @Transactional
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Student> students = session.createQuery("from students",Student.class).list();
        
        return students;
    }
}
```

When run my application, I got this error:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    
    
    root cause
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
        org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
        org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:573)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:361)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
        com.thiluxan.springorm.dao.StudentDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c5b7c8b.getStudents(<generated>)
        com.thiluxan.springorm.HomeController.viewStudents(HomeController.java:33)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:107)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:259)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:267)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:471)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:537)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:573)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:361)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    com.thiluxan.springorm.dao.StudentDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2cb8dc5e.getStudents(<generated>)
    com.thiluxan.springorm.HomeController.viewStudents(HomeController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Do you also have stacktrace for this exception: "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection"?

Comment: @Seb yeah i have added it in the error message

Comment: Hm, not much more information here unfortunately. Could be problem with the connection pool settings. Does it work when you restart the application?

Comment: Your exception stacktrace seems to be incomplete. Please make sure you post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Sorry, I was refraining from answering as I last worked on hibernate many years ago. Things might have changed a lot from then on. Just a question, if you are using Bean to configure the DB details, how you are going to feed it to SessionFactory? Or how actually we are accessing DB properties if not configured through hibernate.cfg.xml or by other means like setting DB properties to Configuration object?

Answer (score -1):

Try this on your jdbcUrl value:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Why do you think this would help? And specifically why all these connection properties? It looks like a random guess to me

Comment: It is not random guess. Mysql connection errors often happens because of time zone differences. Sometimes db does not exist.

Comment: Then explain that in your answer! Don't just throw out a random connection string with the suggestion to try that. You need to support your answer with an explanation and references. However, your reason that time zones might be the cause doesn't  explain all those other connection properties you included. And, without an actual exception in the question, this is still just a guess.